# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'Library.Class'

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am working on a WebSite project...I have c# experience but not HTML or CSS nor much ASP.Net...I am doing the middle-tier portion of a project.  Because my UI teammate has been unabailable I have had to do a portion of her work.  The following is a screenshot of a search page that searches for available training sessions:

[image]

The following is the markup for the GridView for the page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSearchResults" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SessionName">

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlSessName" runat="server" Text='<%#((SophosEngine.Training_Sessions)Container.DataItem).Session_Name%>' NavigateUrl='<%#"~/About.aspx?sid=" + ((SophosEngine.Training_Sessions)Container.DataItem).Session_ID.ToString() %>'>

                    </asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SessionDescription">

                <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:Label ID ="lblTestSessDesc" runat="server" Text='<%#((SophosEngine.Training_Sessions)Container.DataItem).Session_Description%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

The following is the line from the markup that I am getting the `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'SophosEngine.Training_Sessions'.`error on:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlSessName" runat="server" Text='<%#((SophosEngine.Training_Sessions)Container.DataItem).Session_Name%>' NavigateUrl='<%#"~/About.aspx?sid=" + ((SophosEngine.Training_Sessions)Container.DataItem).Session_ID.ToString() %>'>
```

The following is the code for the event handler:

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Search = txbSearch.Text;
            Training_Sessions mySearchedSess = new  Training_Sessions();
            List<Training_Sessions> mySessions;
            mySessions = Training_Sessions.SearchClasses(Search);

            gvSearchResults.DataSource = mySessions;
            gvSearchResults.DataBind();

        }
```

The following is the middle tier code for the `Training_Session` class:

```
public static List<Training_Sessions> SearchClasses(string SearchInput)


   {
        List<Training_Sessions> SearchSessList = new List<Training_Sessions>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=server.database.windows.net,1433,1433;Initial Catalog=Sophos;Integrated Security=False;User ID=SQLadmin;Password=Sophos123;Connect Timeout=10000;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");

    using (conn)
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("@Exception", e).Value = e.ToString();
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Exception (Exception)" + "VALUES (@Exception)";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            command.Parameters.Add("@SessName", SearchInput).Value = SearchInput;
            command.Parameters.Add("@SessDesc", SearchInput).Value = SearchInput;
            command.Parameters.Add("@SessOrgr", SearchInput).Value = SearchInput;

            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Session WHERE SessionName LIKE '%'+ @SessName + '%' OR SessionDescription";// LIKE '%' + @SessDesc + '%' OR Organizer LIKE '%' + @SessOrgr + '%'";

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Loop over the results
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Training_Sessions temp = new Training_Sessions(reader);
                    SearchSessList.Add(temp);
                }
            }

            command.Dispose();
        }

        conn.Close();


        return SearchSessList;
    }
}
```

I'm a bit perplexed because I pretty much copy and pasted the code from the markup from another page that has the same functionality but am getting errors on this one for some reason...again I just know c# but am unfamiliar with asp.net.

May someone please help me rectify this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Container.DataItem` in your error line refers to the data item bound to the current grid row. The code you're invoking appears to expect the rows in the grid to be bound to objects of type `Library.Class`. In your case you have bound the grid to a `SQLDataSource`, which is not yielding objects of that class.

Comment: May you assist me on this error:  `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.`   I get it on this line:  `SearchSessList.Add(temp);`